# Python authentication cookies and django sessions

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I am trying to create an external python client to access a django app. The client should authenticate a user, generate cookies and be able to access the pages just like any browser.

```
login_data_encoded = urllib.urlencode({'user':'sample', 'pass':'secret'})
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
opener.open('http://localhost:8000/login', login_data_encoded)  #problem here
response = opener.open('http://localhost:8000/secret_page')
secret_page = response.read()
```

In python interpreter:

```
import client

client.secret_page
--> []
```

But the page is empty. I can view the page in browser (once logged in as sample user, login works). Django identified me as an Anonymous User (thus due to permissions, it does not let me view the data for sample user) maybe because I have not started a django session for the user. How do I start a django session through the client? (not with a browser)

I hope I have made this clear.

EDIT 1:

It logs me in as Anonymous user, no difference with or without slash. No csrf in code or template. Log of Django shows 200 response, and 200 on getting the secret_page as well. cj contains the cookie information:

```
<cookielib.CookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='app_r12', value='dd070f7acfe37c0474c223287c5adcbe', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='localhost.local', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

The response for opener.open (the POST one) is again 200 and url is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sending the POST request to the wrong url. It was meant to be sent to:

```
opener.open('http://localhost:8000/auth', login_data_encoded)
```

Sorry my mistake. I thought if I sent the request to the login page it would work but the login page was not going to the right view. After changing it to the url with the right view, its works.

Thank you for the answers they were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to post to the login page, save the cookie, then send the cookies along with other subsequent requests. Something like this:

```
import requests

credentials = {'login': 'foo', 'password': 'secret'}
web = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/login',data=credentials)
secure_cookie = web.cookies
web = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/secret_page',cookies=secure_cookie)
the_page = web.text
```

Comment: Sorry web.text doesn't work: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'. How do I view the page?

Comment: Figured it out its web.content, but it just takes me to the login page, not the secret page

Comment: Yes I have checked many times, I think it's got to do with django sessions. It logs me in as an Anonymous User and not sample user.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible issues in you code

- no ending slash in "http://localhost:8000/login" for a POST which can not be redirected when APPEND_SLASH is enabled.
- no csrf_token info in login_data_encoded. Does the login view has csrf_exempt decorated?
- Is there any required field to pass?

You may also

- check log of Django
- check the content of cj
- check the response of opener.open('http://localhost:8000/login', login_data_encoded), include code and current URL

Comment: It logs me in as Anonymous user, no difference with or without slash. No csrf in code or template. Log of Django shows 200 response, and 200 on getting the secret_page as well. cj contains the cookie information. The response for opener.open is again 200 and url is the same.

Comment: @Jimmy Is app_r12 the session key? You could check in session its value if so.