# Browser redirects properly on @login_required but not when using urllib2

Tags: python, django, authentication, urllib2, login-required

I am testing a Django app with a unnitest.TestCase test.

```
if test['auth']:
    full_url = '{}/{}'.format(host, test['url'])
    request = urllib2.Request(full_url)
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    urlh = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
    html = urlh.read()

    doc = BeautifulSoup(html)
    csrf_input = doc.find(attrs = dict(name = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'))
    csrf_token = csrf_input['value']

    params = urllib.urlencode(dict(username = test['username'], password=test['password'], 
           csrfmiddlewaretoken = csrf_token, user=CustomUser.objects.get(id=2), next=test['url']))
    urlh = urllib2.urlopen(full_url, params)
    output = urlh.read()
    print 'Checking {} for "{}" string at {}.'.format(test['url'], test['test_string'], host)
    print output
    if test['test_string'] in output:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The test data coming to this page looks like:

```
{
    'url' : '/manager/',
    'test_string' : 'Manage your jobs',
    'comment' : 'testing string in page',
    'hosts' : (hosts['test'],),
    'auth' : True,
    'username' : 'poster',
    'password' : 'poster',
    'active' : True,
},
```

*for the sake of completeness: hosts['test'] is equal to 'http://:'
it calls the http_string_tester by *for host in hosts: ...*

The page I am trying to check requires the user to be logged in (this page url is "/manager/"):

```
@login_required(login_url='/auth/login/')
def index(request):

    # Get list of jobs that were created by the user
    job_list = Job.objects.filter(poster_id=request.user.id)

    return render_to_response(
        'manager/index.html',
        {
            'page_title'    :   'Manager',   # title for html page
            'app_name'      :   SITENAME,          # Site's proper name
            'job_list'      :   job_list,          
            'request'       :   request,
        },
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )
```

The log in view ('/auth/login/') looks like so:

```
def dologin(request):

    message = 'blah'
    user = []

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(
            username = username,
            password = password,
        )

        if user is not None and hasattr(user, 'verified'):
            if user.verified and user.is_active:
                message = 'authenticated'
                login(request, user)

                # This section seems to be required so that I can redirect properly in 
                # the browser but in the test it seems to be a hindrance.
                if request.POST['next'] is not None:
                    print 'NEXT is '+str(request.POST['next'])
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['next'])
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


        # .............. #

    # The rest
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'next' in request.GET:
        next = request.GET['next']
    else:
        next = None

    print 'NEXT is '+str(next)

    return render_to_response(
        'auth/login.html',
        {
            'page_title' : 'Log in to {}'.format(SITENAME),
            'app_name' : SITENAME,
            'message' : message,
            'next' : next,
        },
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )
```

When I run my test I get the following in the logs (from .manage.py runserver):

```
Development server is running at http://<hostname:port>/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[15/Apr/2013 08:21:53] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
NEXT is /manager/
[15/Apr/2013 08:21:53] "GET /auth/login/?next=/manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2973
[15/Apr/2013 08:21:53] "POST /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
NEXT is /manager/
[15/Apr/2013 08:21:53] "GET /auth/login/?next=/manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2973
```

So, it would appear that I am able to get to /manager/ but with a 302 (redirection -- which makes sense) and then I'm redirected to /auth/login/?next=/manager/ which sends me to /manager/ but again with a 302 back to /auth/login/?next.... so that it tells me it's not accepting this user as logged in. I've verified that this whole process works when I click through my app. These are the steps:

With the web browser I go to http://:/manager/
This redirects me to http://:/auth/login/?next=/manager/ where I log in with 'poster:poster'
This then redirects me to http://:/manager/ and I can see the page as expected.

FWIW, one of my tests simply goes to the login page and can log in and pull expected info from the output but this doesn't seem to work here.

I am seeking some guidance. Using the browser redirects me properly but this urllib2 call doesn't seem to do that. I am hoping someone to shed some light on why this isn't working as I am expecting. If you need any further info, please let me know.

Update:

Response headers are respectively from each open:

```
HEADERS are Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2013 13:42:33 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Vary: Cookie
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=TYEE6upwq20wNoobztYWHlIjnIQ8qc2u; expires=Mon, 14-Apr-2014 13:42:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/

PARAMS are username=poster&csrfmiddlewaretoken=TYEE6upwq20wNoobztYWHlIjnIQ8qc2u&password=poster&user=poster&next=%2Fmanager%2F

RESPONSE HEADERS are Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2013 13:42:33 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Vary: Cookie
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=TYEE6upwq20wNoobztYWHlIjnIQ8qc2u; expires=Mon, 14-Apr-2014 13:42:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

Comment: My guess is it's not setting the cookie[s] correctly, although I'm not sure why. If you included some code to print out all the HTTP request and response headers, it should help track down the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you chose this way instead of the Django TestCase tools, just curious not critiqueing!

Comment: Well, it looks like you're using Django's built-in authentication system, which, IIRC, requires you to also use its built-in session system, but I see no session cookies being set. Does it set any session cookies when using your web browser?

Comment: Hi limelights, very good question, I would prefer to go that way but I've not been able to find a good set of examples that made sense to me or would help me here. The ones I've seen of course are on the django docs site. I am open to that as well (I realize technically off-topic here but would be open nonetheless).

Comment: Aya: I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162850/pass-session-cookies-in-http-header-with-python-urllib2 ... are you referring to something like this possibly?

Comment: Another one that may get us closer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886612/python-authentication-cookies-and-django-sessions

Comment: Well, I think one of the server responses should be returning a `Set-Cookie` header which includes a session ID, but I don't see one. You may have accidentally omitted it, though. I notice your server log shows four requests, but you only pasted two response headers.